# InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type NSURL at profileUrl

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to store Image URL from Xcode and store image into Firebase Storage and Image URL to Firebase Database. I can get to store my image in Firebase Storage but when i try to save image url to firebase database i am getting this error: InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type NSURL at profileUrl. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'
Here is my function code:

```
func uploadImage(_ Image: UIImage?, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?)  -> ()) ){
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("name.png")
        guard let imgData = myImageView.image?.pngData() else { return  }
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/png"
        storageRef.putData(imgData, metadata: metaData) {(metadata, error) in
            if error == nil {
            print("success")
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url,error) in
                    completion(url)
                    print("URL is \(String(describing: url))")
                } )
            }else{
                print("error in save image")
               completion(nil)
            }
                }
    }
            func saveImage(profileURL: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?)  -> ()) ){
        let dict = ["Price": self.label.text ?? "", "profileUrl": profileURL.absoluteURL] as [String : Any]
         self.ref.child("Value").childByAutoId().setValue(dict)
    }
```

And i am calling it here:

```
func saveFIRData() {
        self.uploadImage(self.myImageView.image) { url in
        self.saveImage(profileURL: url!) { success in
         if success != nil {
                    print("SUCCESS")}}}}
```

My code should get a url of image in Firebase database under child "profileUrl".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you can't save an NSURL object, since that is not a valid JSON type. You'll want to store the string version of the URL by calling `profileURL.absoluteString` on it.

```
func saveImage(profileURL: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?)  -> ()) ){
    let dict = ["Price": self.label.text ?? "", "profileUrl": profileURL.absoluteString] as [String : Any]
    self.ref.child("Value").childByAutoId().setValue(dict)
}
```

Comment: I over looked the error! But changing to String worked. Thanks!